# ERR_NGROK_108 using pyngrok

Tags: pyngrok

Really running out of steam trying to figure this puppy out

- Using pyngrok = "^6.0.0"
- Python 3.11.4

I've tried every version documented and simply can't get this to work
I've gone back and forth between pyngrok and ngrok

```py
def start_ngrok() : 
   from pyngrok.conf import PyngrokConfig
   from pyngrok import ngrok, conf


   conf.get_default().config_path = "settings/ngrok.yml"
   tunnel = ngrok.connect(name="app")
    
   #tunnel = ngrok.connect(addr="127.0.0.1:3000", proto="http", bind_tls=True)
   url = tunnel.public_url
```

my settings/ngrok.yml contains

```yaml
region: us
version: '2'
authtoken: XXXXXX
api_key: XXXXXX
tunnels:
  app:
    addr: https://127.0.0.1:3000
    proto: http
    #bind_tls: true
```

I keep getting the following error ERR_NGROK_108

```
2023-08-23 15:57:40,310 - pyngrok.ngrok - INFO - Opening tunnel named: app
2023-08-23 15:57:40,310 - pyngrok.process - INFO - Starting ngrok with config file: settings/ngrok.yml
2023-08-23 15:57:40,313 - pyngrok.process - DEBUG - ngrok process starting with PID: 97578
2023-08-23 15:57:40,322 - pyngrok.process.ngrok - INFO - t=2023-08-23T15:57:40-0400 lvl=info msg="open config file" path=/Users/patrick/Projects/[XXXX]/settings/ngrok.yml err=nil
2023-08-23 15:57:40,323 - pyngrok.process.ngrok - WARNING - t=2023-08-23T15:57:40-0400 lvl=warn msg="can't bind default web address, trying alternatives" obj=web addr=127.0.0.1:4040
2023-08-23 15:57:40,323 - pyngrok.process.ngrok - INFO - t=2023-08-23T15:57:40-0400 lvl=info msg="starting web service" obj=web addr=127.0.0.1:4041 allow_hosts=[]

ERROR:  authentication failed: Your account is limited to 1 simultaneous ngrok agent session.
ERROR:  You can run multiple tunnels on a single agent session using a configuration file.
ERROR:  To learn more, see https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels/ngrok-agent/reference/config/
ERROR:  
ERROR:  Active ngrok agent sessions in region 'us':
ERROR:    - [XXXXX] ([XXXXX])
ERROR:  
ERROR:  ERR_NGROK_108
ERROR:  
2023-08-23 15:57:40,434 - pyngrok.process.ngrok - ERROR - t=2023-08-23T15:57:40-0400 lvl=eror msg="failed to reconnect session" obj=tunnels.session obj=csess id=[XXXX] err="authentication failed: Your account is limited to 1 simultaneous ngrok agent session.\nYou can run multiple tunnels on a single agent session using a configuration file.\nTo learn more, see https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels/ngrok-agent/reference/config/\n\nActive ngrok agent sessions in region 'us':\n  - [XXXXXX]
 ([XXXXX])\r\n\r\nERR_NGROK_108\r\n"
```

Checking the client api

```bash
$ ngrok --config settings/ngrok.yml api tunnel-sessions list
200 OK
{
  "next_page_uri": null,
  "tunnel_sessions": [],
  "uri": "https://api.ngrok.com/tunnel_sessions"
}
```

I've checked the ngrok dashboard no agents are running, no tunnels exist
I can call the CLI just fine

```
16:18 $ which ngrok
/............/env/bin/ngrok

16:17 $ ngrok --config settings/ngrok.yml start app
```

Works fine, it's just using the while using connect it bombs out
And I've run out of ideas

I've used all the connect methods listed in the pydocs

- ngrok.connect(3000) # err_ngrok_3004 defaulted to connect to localhost vs 127.0.0.1 (os x quirk)
- ngrok.connect('https://127.0.0.1') # agent issue ERR_NGROK_108
- ngrok.werkzeug_develop() #err_ngrok_3004

Comment: Try some of these tips:

1. `print(ngrok.conf.DEFAULT_NGROK_PATH))` to find where `pyngrok` has installed `ngrok` for you, clobbert it, start over. Maybe somehow you're running an old `ngrok` 2.x binary (but the docs you're looking at are probably for 3.x)
2. Try not setting `config_path`. Then, set a `config_path` but comment all the configs out. Reintroduce then one-by-one (starting with `authtoken`) until you find the culprit.
3. [Follow the troubleshooting tips](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#test-in-the-python-console) for more log output.

Comment: @alexdlaird I found the issue Flask auto reloader was restarting the app turning it to false causes it to run cleanly - is ngrok creating flies ? pids / state etc?  app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False, port=port, ssl_context=(cert, key))

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, yes. Because the auto-reloader starts two serves, hence the error saying you can’t have another tunnel open. If you had a paid account on `ngrok` my guess is it would work with true.